# Android Media Recorder - Play and record at the same time

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder

I'm making an app like piano, and I want to record the songs that I made and to share them.
Is it possible to play sounds and at the time they play, to record them ?

Comment: `myAudioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.REMOTE_SUBMIX);`

and in Manifest.xml I added the required permmisions, but it doesn't record nothing.

Comment: Submix needs shared user id `android.uid.system` and root permissions on various vendor phones like HTC Samsung may be. And I don't think you need REMOTESUBMIX, as it is used to transmit only device audio stream. If you want to transmit via mic, use `MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC`